# ForFiles command returns different results on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I run the following command in Windows 7 Professional(x64) machine and the result I get does not include sub folders however the same command on Windows 2008 x64 contains sub folders as the result. What is going on here and how can I make sure the result DOES NOT contain the sub directories within the searched folder?

forfiles /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @path"

[The command is always running as an Administrator so there should not be any security issue]

Comment: Why this one is tagged `powerhsell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command generated an error with the period.

This works here, and the likelihood is that one folder contained folders which were being listed.

```
forfiles /m * /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @path"
```

Comment: Thanks foxidrive for the response. the if statement did the trick. In regards to the 'period' I should say the command works fine on my machine even with the *.* so I have no idea why you get error and I also have no idea why the result is different on two different operating systems on my end.

Comment: The period doesn't work on my Win7 machine or my Win 8.1 machine but it works on the V1.1 version of forfiles from 1998.  Maybe you migrated an earlier version.

Comment: Its very odd. I checked the version on both operating systems and they were the same: File version : 6.1.7600.16385   Product version:6.1.7600.16385 Date modified : 14-07-2009

Comment: This is probably an academic point but the Version on my Windows 7 is the same as yours in system32.  Could you have another version of forfiles.exe earlier in the PATH than system32?

Comment: I searched the entire machine for all instances of the forfiles and all instances found had the same version however I completely agree with you. I cant think of any other answer than having different versions of the forfiles.

Comment: `for %a in (forfiles.exe) do echo %~dp$path:a` <--- this command line will tell you where the forfiles.exe which is being executed is located, assuming there is no `forfiles.exe` located in the folder with the batch file.